# Sending excel sheet data into SharePoint list using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to import data into an existing SharePoint list from an Excel sheet.

I want to use C#.

I have a windows application form. On a button click my data should be transfer from an Excel sheet to my SharePoint list.

Comment: This can be done. What code have you got so far? How well is it working? What errors are you getting? What specific issues are you encountering?

Comment: I am not understanding how to start.

Comment: Maybe start reading here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/96d15c60-73db-4970-b22c-877d0adf1d41/read-and-write-excel-sheet-data-from-uploded-file-in-sharepoint-site-programmatically-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment and see if that gets you started.